# FlowLayoutPanel flickers when shown at design time

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

Every time I look at my FlowLayoutPanel (which contains 96 Labels and 96 TextBoxes) at design time, all the controls dance and flash all over the form, as if they've forgotten where they belong for a couple of seconds, before finally reorienting themselves and returning to their proper positions.

It's as if all the controls on the FlowLayoutPanel are tossed into the air, the form then goes blank, repaints itself, and finally redisplays as originally expected.

Is there anything that can be done to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that setting the FlowLayoutPanel's *Locked* Property to True does the trick - it no longer jumps around like a jellyfish - I like it!